# optimizing SQL query with multiple keys

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table in a database with a primary key, and a 'second' key as well.  This second key can have the same value occur more than once in the table, but often i only want to return the most recent row for that second key.  I have an existing query that works below, but I feel like it's very ugly and there should be a simpler way to do this instead of creating a table variable, going through a loop, and inserting 1 row into the table variable on each pass through the loop.  Am i making this too hard?

```
declare @RowCnt int
declare @MaxRows int
declare @secondID as uniqueidentifier
DECLARE @retList TABLE(
firstGUID  uniqueidentifier,
secondGUID  uniqueidentifier,
name nvarchar(50),
DateCreated  datetime
)

select @RowCnt = 1

declare @Import table (rownum int IDENTITY (1, 1) Primary key NOT NULL , secondGUID uniqueidentifier)
insert into @Import (secondGUID) SELECT DISTINCT dbo.TestTable.secondGUID FROM dbo.TestTable 

select @MaxRows=count(*) from @Import
while @RowCnt <= @MaxRows
begin
    select @secondID=secondGUID from @Import where rownum = @RowCnt 

    INSERT INTO @retList
        SELECT     TOP (1) firstGUID,secondGUID,name,datecreated
        FROM         dbo.TestTable
        WHERE dbo.TestTable.secondGUID = @secondID
        ORDER BY DateCreated Desc

    Set @RowCnt = @RowCnt + 1
END

select * from @retList
```

EDIT:
for example, imagine the table has these values

```
    firstGUID                                secondGUID                              Name     DateCreated
    EAD50999-E9B1-43F0-9FA6-615405FA5A9A     6163B6ED-6AF4-494E-ACE6-184F4804847B    Test1   2014-04-11 15:12:36.303
    A9645486-1021-4E98-92AC-1205CC3FB9D3     6163B6ED-6AF4-494E-ACE6-184F4804847B    Test2  2014-04-10 15:21:46.087
    DEE375BB-BFAF-44BE-AC64-06D7702E2ACB     3BD0A2F0-4E44-43B9-BD24-003B518609C7    Test3
2014-04-11 15:22:37.097
```

I only want the Test1 and Test3 rows to be returned.

Comment: if the "second" key can be present on more than one row in the table, it is NOT a key.  Whether it is the primary key or an alternate key, to be a key, it MUST be unique.

Comment: I'm not arguing that point, that's why i had it in quotes.  It's a key in the sense that i want the response of my query to only have one result back from that key (so it is unique in the query), but no, it's not unique in the table.  Hence the complicated query.

Comment: Seriously, the word "key" has an unambiguous and well-understood meaning when used in the context of relational databases.  You would be better understood if you chose another word for what you mean here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use SQLServer's analytical functions:

```
select firstGUID, secondGUID, name, datecreated
from (select t.*, 
             rank() over (partition by secondGUID order by datecreated desc) r
      from TestTable t) ilv
where r=1
```

Comment: This works (thanks!) in that it returns the same values back as my original query, but the analytical functions are a completely new territory for me.  Is this faster/better than the setup i have above?

Comment: @Phil: I would *expect* it to be faster, since it only involves one pass over the table.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure I understand what you're asking, but it sounds like you want to select only the rows containing the max DateCreated.  The normal way of doing that is to join with a subselect that uses a group by clause, eg.:

```
select tt.*
from TestTable tt
join (
    select firstguid, max(DateCreated) as maxdate
    from TestTable
    group by firstguid
) gtmp on tt.firstguid = gtmp.firstguid and tt.dateCreated = gtmp.maxdate
```

Comment: the max datecreated for each 'secondguid'.  Meaning i can have 3 rows, each with unique 'firstguid' values, but 2 with the same 'secondguid' values.  I want my query to return 2 rows back.  The duplicate 'secondguid' row that is returned is the most recent one.

Comment: You lost me at "2 rows back".  If you could edit your question and add some data representing what you have -- and what you would like to produce, then it would be easier to come up with a solution.